# Is there a linux command that lets me color-code the result of another command?

Tags: linux, command-line, colors, watch

I'm running a `watch` on a command to monitor the number of open connections for a service we're diagnosing.  I need to keep an eye on it while doing other work, to help other developers identify when the service is acting up.

The result of the watch is a number between 1 and 5000.  I'd like to show the number as green when it's below 500, yellow when its between 501 and 4000, and red for above 4000.

Is there a command which can set the color easily based on the value of my command?

Comment: I'm not familiar with linux :) "watch" - means show std out in terminal?

Comment: @Maximus It's a linux utility which repeatedly executes a command and displays the output in a terminal at a specified interval. `watch -n 1 ps aux` -- A poor man's process monitor, for example (execute `ps aux` to list processes every `1` second and print the results).

Comment: Just to tell you: there is colordiff for all those nasty diff commands. Eg. svn diff |colordiff -> woho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this small script that I named color:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$($@)

GREEN="1;32m"
YELLOW="1;33m"
RED="1;31m"

if [ "$result" -lt "500" ]
then
        echo -e "\033[$GREEN  $result  \033[0m" ;
elif [ "$result" -ge "500" -a "$result" -le "4000" ]
then
        echo -e "\033[$YELLOW  $result  \033[0m" ;
else
        echo -e "\033[$RED  $result  \033[0m" ;
fi
```

You can now run:

```
watch --color ./color <your command here>
```

Make sure your command just output a number. Else you got to handle the output correctly and assign it to `result` variable.

Answer (score 3):

[CCZE](http://freecode.com/projects/ccze) may be what you're looking for:
<sup>[man page over at Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/ccze.1.html)</sup>

[image]

### Installation

On Debian-based systems, you can easily install it via

```
sudo apt-get install ccze
```

### Usage

Use it like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | ccze
```

### Plugins

If the default coloring behavior of `ccze` is not to your liking, you can extend the functionality through plugins. Sadly, I have never written any as I'm served well with the default behavior, so I can only direct you to the [`ccze-plugin` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ccze-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can [color the man pages](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BFaLAa428k), however (after running several [Google](http://google.com) searches, I don't think what you're looking for exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tput` to to put some color in your life. Examples are

```
tput setf 3 # textcolor green
tput setf 6 # red
tput sgr0 # back to normal
echo "$(tput setf 6)$line$(tput setf sgr0)"
```

This and more fun with tput on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-learningtput/